# How to deploy to AEM instance via Repository?

Tags: java, content-management-system, aem

Is it possible/ how do you take an packaged version of a jar via a repository (for example Artifactory) and deploy it to an instance of AEM?
Could this be done via Maven and Jenkins in an automated way?

Currently this is done, only by using a tagged version in a VCS to build and then deploy via the content-package-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

With Jenkins you have multiple options:

- You could let Maven build the artifacts for you
- or you could use the Repository Connector Plugin (1) to get the artifacts from Nexus / Artifactory

After that, just use the CRX Content Package Deployer Plugin (2) to upload the packages to your AEM instance.

The Jenkins build could be triggered manually, by change in the VCS,...

(1): https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin

(2): https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CRX+Content+Package+Deployer+Plugin

Comment: Aha, looks like all I am missing the is the CRX Content Package Deployer Plugin.
I was looking how to use it via Maven, but this is a cleaner approach as there is no need to do a build.